# Autocompletetextview to select text only from drop down listing

Tags: android

I have **autocompletetextview** where I want only those text which is in my **raw** resource text file where I have all names stored and displaying in auto suggestion **list**
If user tries to enter **different** text other than the listing then validate to show : **"Selected names accepted only"**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button submit;
    TextView timerInfo;
    TextView timertext;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    Scanner scanner;
    ArrayList<String> list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    AutoCompleteTextView autolist;
    AccessibilityService.SoftKeyboardController keyboardController;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        scanner= new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.names)).useDelimiter("\n");
        list=new ArrayList<>();

        getList();


        autolist=(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.list_names);

        autolist.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus && v.getId()==R.id.list_names){
                    autolist.setCursorVisible(true);
                    populate();
                }
                else{
                    ((AutoCompleteTextView)v).performValidation();
                    autolist.setCursorVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });
    autolist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            autolist.setCursorVisible(true);
        }
    });


        autolist.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event != null&& (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    autolist.setCursorVisible(false);
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(autolist.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }

        });
        pref=getSharedPreferences("AppClose",MODE_PRIVATE);

           String abc=pref.getString("demover","");
        if(abc=="demover"){
            finish();
        }

        submit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.timerStart);
         timerInfo=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerInfo);
         timertext=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.timertxt);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timertext.setText("Time Left :");
                submit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                countDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(30000,1000){

                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                       timerInfo.setText(String.valueOf((int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000)));

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        pref.edit().putString("demover","demover").apply();
                        finish();
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });

autolist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
         isSelectedText = true;
     }

 });
    autolist.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            isSelectedText = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
              if(isSelectedText){
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "nice", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
            else{
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "not nice", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
        }
    });
    }
    class Validator implements AutoCompleteTextView.Validator {

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(CharSequence text) {
            Log.v("Test", "Checking if valid: "+ text);
            Arrays.sort(new InputStream[]{getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.names)});
            if (Arrays.binarySearch(new InputStream[]{getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.names)}, text.toString()) > 0) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence fixText(CharSequence invalidText) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fixed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            /* I'm just returning an empty string here, so the field will be blanked,
             * but you could put any kind of action here, like popping up a dialog?
             *
             * Whatever value you return here must be in the list of valid words.
             */
            return "Digger";
        }
    }


    public void getList(){
        try{
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                list.add(scanner.next());
            }
        }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    public void populate(){
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
        autolist.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

I have used debugger on somelines and it shows **suspended** thread.

**What I want :** Only those text to be taken as input which are in auto suggestion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. AutoCompleteTextView has a listener for the suggested items. So, if the item is clicked then set the status to true else it remails
>      false
> 2. User can select and the modify so add a TextWatcher to change the status to false if the text is changed.
> 3. Do your desired action with a if/else from isSelectedText

```
    autoText.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            isSelectedText = true;
        }

    });


    autoText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            isSelectedText = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: will there be no conflict suppose you choose an item from drop down ok now you want to change and choose another item from list so onTextChanged will called and isSelectedText will be false always even if you choose your text from suggestion still it would be false

Comment: changes text > false > selects item > true.  Thus , no possible conflicts

Comment: Perfect Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead of using scanner.

```
try {
        Resources res = getResources();
        InputStream in = res.openRawResource(R.raw.names);

        byte[] byte = new byte[in.available()];
        in .read(btye);
        list.add(new String(btye));
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: I guess i am getting name list in ArrayList but you haven't told me what I have actually asked for . How to take inputs only from suggestion box and if entered something on their own then display "something"